# If Current Date is in Column Then Show Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in excel that the column header is the month and the rows are the days. I need to get today's current date which i have already done. Once i do this i need to match the month and day with the column "cy_day".

Example:
if todays day is jan 3 then it should only return "2".

Excel File:

```
cy_day    jan   feb  mar
1           1   1    1
2           3   2    4
3           4   4    5
4           7   5    6



import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import calendar

cycle_day_path = 'test\\Documents\\cycle_day_calendar.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(cycle_day_path)
df = DataFrame(df, index=None)
print(df)

month = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%b")
day = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%d")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
today = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-03')
col = today.strftime('%b').lower()
df[df[col] == today.day]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you've extracted month using '%b', it should just be this after correcting for the upper case in '%b' month name (see http://strftime.org/):

```py
df.loc[df[month.lower()] == day, 'cy_day']
```

Now for Jan 3 you will get 2 (as a DataFrame). If you want just the number 2 do:

```py
df.loc[df[month.lower()] == day, 'cy_day'].values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of the `month` variable as returned by `pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%b")` is a capitalized string, so in order to use is to access column from yo your dataframe should lowercase it.

so first you should do

```
month = month.lower()
```

after date you need to make sure that the values in your month columns are of type `str` since you are going to compare them with an str value.

```
day_of_month = df[month] == day
df["cy_day"][day_of_month]
```

if they are not of type str, you  should convert the `day` variable to the same type as the month columns